# ActiveMQ servlet connect with java client

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, activemq-classic

I'm trying to connect from Java to a running ActiveMQ servlet(on Weblogic 12), but I'm getting the following exception on `conn.start();`:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not post command: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:lmdesetup-jab-38449-1378221016985-2:1, clientId = ID:lmdesetup-jab-38449-1378221016985-1:1, clientIp = null, userName = null, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = false, failoverReconnect = false} due to: java.io.IOException: Failed to post command: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:lmdesetup-jab-38449-1378221016985-2:1, clientId = ID:lmdesetup-jab-38449-1378221016985-1:1, clientIp = null, userName = null, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = false, failoverReconnect = false} as response was: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Connection: close, Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 15:11:02 GMT, Content-Length: 3092, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2]
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1409)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1496)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:524)
```

The code is here:

```
QueueConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("http://localhost:8888/myApp/amq");
Connection conn = factory.createConnection();
conn.start();
```

(The code is based on this example: http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)

I'm quite sure the ActiveMQ broker and AjaxServlet are fine, because I can send and receive messages using js client.

The servlet is defined like this in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
    <param-value>vm://localhost</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

I have found someone wlse with the same problem, but the solution is not there: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.activemq.user/month=20090501

Here's the exception from Weblogic:

```
      ####<Sep 3, 2013 4:19:32 PM UTC> <Error> <Kernel> <mymachine> <myServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1378225172656> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can NOT error at this state: AsyncCompleted.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can NOT error at this state: AsyncCompleted
at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.DefaultState.notifyError(AsyncStates.java:62)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncContextImpl.handleError(AsyncContextImpl.java:125)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.DispatchHandler.run(DispatchHandler.java:33)
 at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
 >
 ####<Sep 3, 2013 4:19:32 PM UTC> <Error> <HTTP> <mymachine> <myServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1378225172779> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1154401993[app:ino-all module:ino path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: A destination must be specified.
     at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:257)
     at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:224)
     at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:300)
     at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.send(WebClient.java:243)
     at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageListenerServlet.doPost(MessageListenerServlet.java:219)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
     at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
```

Comment: Does any stacktrace get printed to the Weblogic console/standard output log? You're getting a `response was: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` response which would seem to indicate the server got the request but encountered an uncaught exception when handling it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was looking at the wrong log file. I'm adding it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to create an `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in your Java client if you are going to try using the Ajax servlet. If you look at the [javascript files](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/js/amq.js) bundled with the distribution, all the javascript is doing is constructing a POST request to put a message to a queue.

If you look at the [Client Sending messages](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html) section of the ActiveMQ Ajax docs it explains a little of what happens behind the scene. So I think if you want to use the AjaxServlet for your Java client you would need to construct a [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) similar to the way the javascript is creating a `XMLHttpRequest`.

Alternatively, If you want to follow the example that you linked to, I believe you would need to connect like this:

```
// Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

// Create a Connection
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

`tcp://localhost:61616` should work because [by default](http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html) ActiveMQ adds a tcp connector on port 61616.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I should make clear what I want to accomplish. I have existing clients which are coded against JMS specification and a firewall restrictions. So I'd like to switch the clients to ActiveMQ JMS implementation and communicate via http. Using tcp or not using JMS is unfortunately not an option for me. Maybe I'm trying to do something which is impossible, but I feel I'm quite close to the solution.